# How to return a reactive dataframe from within a shiny module that depends on a button click?

Tags: r, shiny, module, reactive, dt

Aim: Return a reactive dataframe object from within the module named "modApplyAssumpServer"
Problem: I am getting an endless loop.  Even if I wrap everything within the observeevent logic within isolate()

I have included another table in the app code below to indicate a simplified version of the logic that works outside of the module framework but that I can't seem to get to work within the module.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df_agg_orig <- data.frame(proj_1 = c(2,3))

modGrowthInput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
    numericInput(ns("first"),label = "Assumption",value = 100),
  )
}

 modGrowthServer <- function(id, btnGrowth) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      list(
        first = reactive({input$first})
        )
   })
 }

modButtonUI <- function(id,lbl = "Recalculate"){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(inputId = ns("btn"),label = lbl)#,style = "pill",color = "primary",no_outline = T,size = "xs"
}

modButtonServer <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    reactive({input$btn})
  })
}


modApplyAssumpServer <- function(id,btnGrowth, df_agg,case_vals){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    stopifnot(is.reactive(btnGrowth))
    stopifnot(is.reactive(df_agg))
        mod_vals <- reactiveVal(df_agg())
         observeEvent(btnGrowth(),{
           isolate({mod_vals(df_agg() %>% mutate(proj_1 = proj_1*input$first))})
           print("Looping problem...")
           })
      mod_vals()
  })
}

#### Test App
GrowthInputApp <- function() {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(modGrowthInput("tst"),modButtonUI("tstGrowth")),
    mainPanel(fluidRow( splitLayout( DT::DTOutput("no_module"),DT::DTOutput("module_tbl")))))

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    btnGrowth <- modButtonServer("tstGrowth")
    case_vals <- modGrowthServer("tst")
    
    df_agg <- reactiveValues(df_wide = df_agg_orig)
    
    #Outside of module test exhibiting expected/desired behavior (at least if the looping issue would let it do so :)
    observeEvent(btnGrowth(),{
      df_agg$df_wide$proj_1 <- round(df_agg$df_wide*case_vals$first(),2)
       })

    output$no_module <- DT::renderDT({DT::datatable(rownames = F,df_agg$df_wide,caption = "Not Updated Within Module")})
    
    output$module_tbl <- DT::renderDT({DT::datatable(rownames = F,modApplyAssumpServer("tst",btnGrowth = btnGrowth,df_agg = reactive({df_agg_orig})),caption = "Table Returned From Module")}
    )
  
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
  
}
runApp(GrowthInputApp())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df_agg_orig <- data.frame(proj_1 = c(2,3))

modGrowthInput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    numericInput(ns("first"),label = "Assumption",value = 10),
  )
}

modGrowthServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    list(
      first = reactive({input$first})
    )
  })
}

modButtonUI <- function(id,lbl = "Recalculate"){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(inputId = ns("btn"),label = lbl)#,style = "pill",color = "primary",no_outline = T,size = "xs"
}

modButtonServer <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    reactive({input$btn})
  })
}


modApplyAssumpServer <- function(id,btnGrowth, df_agg, val){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    stopifnot(is.reactive(btnGrowth))
    stopifnot(is.reactive(df_agg))
    
    modvals <- eventReactive(btnGrowth(), {
      print("Looping problem...")
      #print(btnGrowth())
      df_agg() %>% mutate(proj_1 = proj_1*val )
    })
    return(modvals())
  })
}

#### Test App
GrowthInputApp <- function() {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(modGrowthInput("tst"),modButtonUI("tstGrowth")),
    mainPanel(fluidRow( splitLayout( DT::DTOutput("no_module"),DT::DTOutput("module_tbl")))))
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    btnGrowth <- modButtonServer("tstGrowth")
    case_vals <- modGrowthServer("tst")
    observe({ print(case_vals$first())})
    df_agg <- reactiveValues(df_wide = df_agg_orig)
    
    #Outside of module test exhibiting expected/desired behavior (at least if the looping issue would let it do so :)
    observeEvent(btnGrowth(),{
      df_agg$df_wide$proj_1 <- round(df_agg$df_wide*case_vals$first(),2)
    })
    
    mydf <- eventReactive(c(btnGrowth(),case_vals$first()), {
      modApplyAssumpServer("tst", btnGrowth, reactive({df_agg$df_wide}), case_vals$first() )
    })
    #observe({print(btnGrowth())})
    output$no_module <- renderDT({DT::datatable(rownames = F,df_agg$df_wide,caption = "Not Updated Within Module")})
    
    output$module_tbl <- renderDT({DT::datatable(rownames = F, mydf() ,caption = "Table Returned From Module")} )
    
    ###  using original data so no change after first click 
    #output$module_tbl <- renderDT({DT::datatable(rownames = F, modApplyAssumpServer("tst", btnGrowth, reactive({df_agg_orig}), case_vals$first() ),caption = "Table Returned From Module")}
    #)
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
  
}
runApp(GrowthInputApp())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! changing it to an event reactive does seem to have resolved the issue of looping.  That being said, I'm getting strange behavior with this new version you sent back, the first button click worked like a charm however after that the button appears to stop working... restarting the app gets a different number of working "clicks" but it also stops working.  Replicated several times. thoughts?

Comment: I should add the button is still working as the non-module logic continues to update the table while the module logic driven table stops updating. No errors appear to be thrown.

Comment: You response will be dependent on the third argument of `modApplyAssumpServer(...)`.  If it is `df_orig` (static data), then it is changed only once.  If you use `df_agg$df_wide`, then it should change on every click.  Please change the `input$first` value to 2 or 4 and see how many clicks you can do.  As the number becomes huge, it might become a problem.

Comment: Please try the updated code.  It appears that calling `modApplyAssumpServer(...)` inside renderDT does not always behave consistently.